# How to fetch remote data page by page using kendo grid in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid

I am trying to fetch remote data(millions of rows) and showing in kendo grid. As a regular approach its fetching all data at a time But I want data according to page size like if `pageSize : 1000` rows. When I load grid first time then fetch first 1000(1-1000) rows when I clicked on next page then fetch next 1000(1001-2000) rows. Similar for all data. How it possible in kendo grid and jsp?

I used datasource like this

```
dataSource: {
      type: "json",
      transport: {
      read: {
       url:".../ProjectWebServices/rest/Report/itemWiseSale",
                       dataType : 'json',
                       type: 'post'
       },

                   parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        if(operation == "read"){
                            options.fromDate = moment($("#start").val()).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            options.toDate = moment($("#end").val()).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            options.storeID = restaurantNumber;

                        }
                   }
           },

                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true,
            schema:{
                  data: function(result) {     
                       return result.data || result;
                     },
                  total: function(result) { 
                         var data = this.data(result);
                         return data ? data.length : 0;
                     }, 
                model: {
                    fields: {

                        //Fields declare here
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 1000,

             group: {
                //Grouping fields here
            }, 
            aggregate: [
               //aggregating fields here
            ] 
    },
```